# App with  WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission is not available to Galaxy Tab 10.1 GT-P7500 on Android Market

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, galaxy, apn

I have found that Android **application with WRITE_APN_SETTINGS permission is not available to Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 GT-P7500** on Android Market. I can see also from developer console that app is not available to this device.

On the other hand, here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html is mentioned that "Strictly, Android Market does not filter based on 'uses-permission' elements".

**When I removed following line**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

**from manifest, app became suddenly available on Market and developer console confirm support of GT-P7500.**

Here is a link to device specification http://acellphonereviews.com/samsung-galaxy-tab-10-1-3g-gt-p7500-review-price-specs.html.

Does anybody have explanation for this Market filtering behaviour and can help how to make app with APN permission available for GT-P7500 ?

Thanks for any hint, Gudaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that, implicit, `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` adds the `android.hardware.telephony` feature to your app? Try adding this feature by hand and set it to [`required=false`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html). (Don't forget to check if the feature is available on the device manually, i.e. avoid the NPE if the feature is not available.)

Answer (score 2):

I solved problem by adding following to manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```